# Quickly create many shapes in Visio from text file

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a text file with many items, each on its own line. I want to create a Visio diagram with a rectangle shape for each item, and with each rectangle's text set to the item.

Is there a quick way to do this?

I have enough items that it would be time consuming to do by hand. I just want to create the initial shapes so I can arrange and work with them in the diagram.

Comment: There could be a VBA approach. How many items you have in the text file? Are those single words or a line containing a few words? How do you want to place the rectangles on Visio Diagram, one below the other or next to each other?

Comment: Question updated. VBA could work, but I was not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote!

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a VBA that should do the trick for you.

A few assumptions

- It's A4 page size with Portrait Layout.
- 4 Rectangles are placed next to each other.
- The font size of the text adjusts itself to the height of the rectangle, rather than altering the shape size.
- The text file contains items one below the other

You may need to study the code and alter it to match your requirement. E.g. You may want to have a bigger sized rectangle than what I have created. Or you may need to remove the inner `For Next` Loop and just place them one below the other and so on.

Open a blank Visio diagram. Set Metric Units. Press ALT + F11 to access VBA Editor. Insert a Module from the Insert Menu. Put the following code into it.

```
Public Sub DrawRectangle_Example()
Dim vsoPages As Visio.Pages
Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
Dim vsoDocument As Visio.Document
Dim Textline As String
Const File1 = "C:\Temp\"  'Set path here
Const File2 = "Visio.txt" 'Set filename with extension here
Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
Open File1 & File2 For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
     For i = 11.3 To 1.1 Step -0.6
          For j = 0.5 To 6.2 Step 1.9
            Set vsoShape = ActivePage.DrawRectangle(j, i, j + 1.5, i - 0.3)
            Line Input #1, Textline
            vsoShape.Text = Textline
            vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "MIN(1,Height/TEXTHEIGHT(TheText,Width))*13&""pt"""
            If EOF(1) Then
               GoTo myend
            End If
          Next j
     Next i

     If EOF(1) Then
        GoTo myend
     End If

     Set vsoDocument = ActiveDocument
     Set vsoPages = vsoDocument.Pages
     Set vsoPage = vsoPages.Add

Loop

myend:
    Close #1
End Sub
```

There are two constants defined in the code. You need to set the path and the file name there referring to your text file.

```
Const File1 = "C:\Temp\"  'Set path here
Const File2 = "Visio.txt" 'Set filename with extension here
```

On the blank Visio page press ALT + F8 and run this macro. Wait for a few seconds and rectangles with inline text as respective line items from your text file shall appear on Visio page. If it fills one page, it will insert a next page and so on.

Try this out and check if this works for you.